# How to retrieve and filter data from json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm now trying to import a JSON file to server and retrieve and filter data from this JSON file and adding it to the database.

I want to treat each element in JSON as one equipment.

Here is what equipment contained in my database:

```
- equipmentName
 - equipmentNumber
 - equipmentType
```

and here is a part of JSON file:

```
{
    "element0": {
        "address": "..."
    },
    "element1": {
        "type": "...",
        "interface": "...",
        "address": ..
    },
    "element2": {
        "interface": "...",
        "address": "...",
        "Class": "..."
    },
    "element3": {
        "channel": ...,
        "Class": "...",
    },
    "element4": {
        "channel": ...,
        "Class": "...",
    }
}
```

Basically I want to set "element#" as both equipmentName and equipmentNumber, and Class as equipmentType and this application will only need to add the elements which contain "Class", for example, the element2, element3 and element4 above.

I tried to to get and set but I cannot let the application to ignore the element which does not contain "Class" and the nullReference exception raised. Need a tutorial or some tips to finish this retrieve and filter process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need deserialize your JSON first of all. So then you can filter and select your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(yourString);` YourObject will need to be a class that the string can be deserialized into. I'm not sure what you need exactly, but it's probably something like this:

```
public class Equipment
{
    //any variables you'll want go here with {get; set;}
    public string Class {get; set;} 
}
```